# Migrate data from old database then import it to new database

Tags: mysql

I have two databases Im working with.
The old database has an older table where the new database holds a brand new table which doesn't have the same table layout as the old.
Im trying to import data from an old table in an old database to a newer database and newer table.
I want to map the data from the old table to the new table.

Right now, the two tables are built like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_old` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE `table_new` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sectional` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `item` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

Initially, I thought I could :

```
INSERT INTO newDatabase.table1 (Column1, Column2) 
SELECT column1, column2 FROM oldDatabase.table1;'
```

However, I think does not fix the issue with how the new table doesn't match the older table.

Some of thw data that I want to insert from the old table looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table_old` (`id`, `name`, `status`)
VALUES
   (1,'Name', 1);
```

I need the new insert to look something like:

```
INSERT INTO `table_new` (`id`, `sectional`, `item`, `name`, `display`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1, NULL, NULL, 'Name', NULL, 1);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Provide example data for `table_old` (in INSERT INTO form) and according data in `table_new` (in formatted table form) with matching explanations.

Comment: This question will probably get closed soon. However, I recommend you to [use HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=export_sql) to perform your import/export operation.